# Google apps script rename file not working

Tags: google-apps-script

When running this script I get the error 
TypeError: Cannot find function setName in object File. (line 8, file "Code")

```
function rename() {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Folder');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  for (var i in files) {
    oldName = files[i].getName()
    newName = oldName.replace(/\d+/g, '')
    newName = newName.replace(/\s/g, '');
    files[i].setName(newName)

  }
```

Comment: please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392391/how-can-you-get-script-to-look-at-a-certain-sheet-in-a-spreadsheet/24392831#24392831) - the part about autocomplete - and you'll avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is rename() and not setName()

```
files[i].rename(newName)
```

Comment: Getting error. `TypeError: Cannot find function getName in object function next() {/* */}.`

Answer (score 6):

For me worked with setName().

```
files[i].setName(newName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() 
{    **// this worked for me rename files of type CSV to processed**
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID'); // change accordingly to  folder ID
//give me only files that are of type CSV
var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV); 
// new name of csv that I want to rename the file within my google drive folder
var newName = "processed";
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
        // iterate throught the csv files available
        var file = files.next()
        // will rename all csv's to processed
        file.setName(newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: great article from https://yagisanatode.com/2018/11/16/google-apps-script-how-to-change-the-file-name-of-non-native-files-like-ms-word-docs-pdfs-and-excel-files/