# Renaming a file in Google Drive / Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I am having trouble renaming a file in Google Drive. I am able to grab the file ok, but once i grab it i need to rename it if it contains a specific string.

I have tried both the .rename() and .setName() functions but Google Drive keeps saying the function can not be found. Any thoughts on how to rename a Google Spreadsheet / file in Google Drive?

```
/* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Get the SpreadSheets Name and Rename it */
    var newSSName = sheet.getName();

    if(newSSName.search("Tr")>=0){
    newSSName.setName("Sheet5");     
    } else if (newSSName.search("Params")>=0){
    newSSName.setName("Sheet4");
    } else if (newSSName.search("MrSummary")>=0){
    newSSName.setName("Sheet3");
    } else {
    newSSName.setName("Sheet2");
    };
```

Comment: Please have a look on https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/AP9zMPOyjfg  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463870/google-apps-script-rename-file-not-working

Comment: What does the Google Drive Documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very simple problem. Let's see what you are trying to do:

`newSSName.setName("Sheet5")`

which we can see as per code is actually

`var newSSName = sheet.getName();`

which actually returns a `string` type. Instead what you need to do is

`sheet.setName("Sheet5");`

which you seem to have gotten right here

```
var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

/* Get the SpreadSheets Name and Rename it */
var newSSName = sheet.getName();
```

So you simply target the wrong variable. Please look up the Google Documentation about the [setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String)) method